# Atlassian Bamboo Builds Docker Images with Permission Errors

Tags: java, gradle, dockerfile, bamboo

I have a `Dockerfile` that I build in Bamboo. See below:

```
FROM gradle:6.8.3-jdk8 AS gradleBuild

WORKDIR /home/gradle/project

COPY --chown=gradle:gradle . /home/gradle/project

RUN gradle build --stacktrace

FROM openjdk:11-jre

COPY --from=gradleBuild /home/gradle/project/build/libs/app.jar ./app.jar

#ENTRYPOINT ["java","-jar","/app.jar"]
```

When I build this image using Bamboo, I encounter the error below:

```
standard_init_linux.go:219: exec user process caused: permission denied
```

However, when I build the image on an Ubuntu machine, I can run the built Docker image successfully.

I also tried doing a `chmod +x` on the JAR file just to make sure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To resolve this, I had to change the default `umask` of Bamboo to `0002`. Since I was running Bamboo using Docker, I just used an environment variable `UMASK=0002`.